# Web location read from mysql database by sessionID

Tags: php, html, mysqli, pdo

this is my problem. each user should have specific "dashboard" and they should be blocked if user is not logged in. So user1 ==> login==> go to dasboard 1 etc. Dashboard locations are saved in mysql database in specific field. I am using login/sigup form in php and this works. when user is logged comes to welcome page.I want add iframe/content from link in db to be visible for that session user.

I tried loading session element, and displaying it but it dont works and I dont get any errors.

```
     if($stmt->execute()){
            // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                    $id = $row["id"];
                    $page = $row["location"];
                    $username = $row["username"];
                    $hashed_password = $row["password"];
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        // Password is correct, so start a new session
                        session_start();

                        // Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username; 
                        $_SESSION["location"] = $page;

                        // Redirect user to welcome page
                        header("location: welcome.php");
```

and this is welcome.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login         page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: log.php");
exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["username"]); ?>     </b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
</div>
 <?php echo $_SESSION ["location"]; ?>
<p>
    <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Your Password</a>
    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a>
</p>
```

Comment: `session_start();` should be set before outputting to the Browser.

Comment: @StackSlave ther is just on beggining of welcome.php, code before has it also but I didnt paste whole code as it is too long.

Comment: Is it actually getting to the welcome page?  What are the values of `$password`, `$hashed_password` (well, don't put it here; but do they match and are not both blank)?  What does `print_r($row)` report (without password, of course)?

Comment: Yes it goes to welcome page, passwords are fine, not blank,  on welcome page I get "username loggedin" Welcome to our page... reset password and sign out button, but link address that is stored in "location" row in db is not showing... link is for example http://mywebsite/user1/

Comment: @TimMorton I get website address as string instead of loading webpage...

Comment: You mean where you `<?php echo $_SESSION ["location"]; ?>`?  if what you stored on the database is a website address, then yes, it will dutifully print out the exactly the same text you stored.  If that data is a file on your system, you'll need to actually load the file with something like https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php